# Tomcat throws and exception when 'Cookie' header is not correct

Tags: tomcat, cookies

If I'll send incorrect cookie value like
`Cookie: привет-мир!` (illegal russian chars) tomcat will throw an exception:

```
Feb 21, 2013 6:29:16 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor process
SEVERE: Error processing request
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Control character in cookie value or attribute.
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.CookieSupport.isHttpSeparator(CookieSupport.java:193)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Cookies.getTokenEndPosition(Cookies.java:488)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Cookies.processCookieHeader(Cookies.java:291)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Cookies.processCookies(Cookies.java:168)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Cookies.getCookieCount(Cookies.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.parseSessionCookiesId(CoyoteAdapter.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.postParseRequest(CoyoteAdapter.java:688)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:402)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1600)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Can I configure tomcat to skip cookie parsing in this case and process request?